# CURL SFTP - How to preserve the last modified date while downloading

Tags: shell, curl, sftp

I'm trying to download a file from another server but I also need to get the last modified date or the last timestamp of the file. I use curl sftp so that I don't have to enter my password every time I run it and I'm also going to run the curl command in perl program.

In SFTP I can preserve it by doing this command: `get -p filename.txt`

In my curl command, this is what I did:

```
curl -v -R -u user:userpass sftp://ip.add.re.ss:port/host/path/name/filename.txt > filename.txt
```

But whenever I run this command, the timestamp is always updated.

Can someone help me to download the file and preserve the last modified date and time?

Comment: -R doesn't work with `>` it requires -o, `curl -R -o filename.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-R doesn't work with `>` it requires `-o`

```
curl -R -o filename.txt -u user:userpass sftp://ip.add.re.ss:port/host/path/name/filename.txt
```

when you use `>` that's not really a command for curl, it's a command for your shell, it tells your shell to save curl's output to a file, and your shell doesn't understand -R. but -o tells curl to save the output to a file instead of printing the file, and curl understands -R

Comment: Hi thank you for explaining it to me. I tried to update the details and run this but it is not working it doesn't even download the file

Comment: @Ekwita that's strange. what do you get from `curl -o pwd1970 -R -u dhtests:yTJLHgQBoc2H8Wi 'sftp://dhtests.ratma.net:/home/dhtests/pwd1970' ; stat pwd1970;`  ?

Comment: Hi this is what I get: curl:  `(51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`

Comment: And I also compared the command in my question and also the one that you gave to me the results are just the same. except that the command in my question downloaded the file

Comment: @Ekwita oh seems you have a ssl certificate store problem then.. do you have an ancient OS past its end-of-life? eg Ubuntu 16.04 became EOL on 30 april 2021.. what do you get from ```curl --insecure -o pwd1970 -R -u dhtests:yTJLHgQBoc2H8Wi 'sftp://dhtests.ratma.net:/home/dhtests/pwd1970' ; stat pwd1970;``` ?

Comment: I tried to run yours and it works, unfortunately when I tried to replace with my details. It just simply downloaded the file.

Comment: Hi I found another way to download the file while preserving the timestamp but i'm not using the curl anymore since it did not working on my end. I'm using expect command. anyways, thank you for helping me

Comment: Ah example such as `curl -R -o myfile.exe https://remote.site/file.exe`does not work.  The downloaded file does not retain it's last modified timestamp.

Comment: @jimjamz probably a server header issue.. what url?

Comment: @hanshenrik - Sorry, it was a while ago and don't remember the URL. I should have mentioned that I also have a _.wgetrc_ file (`timestamping = on, use_server_timestamps = yes`) in my home directory, which enforces the server's last modified timestamp (if available) onto the local file, yet with the above `curl` command and parameters, it was not able to retain it in the same way wget could.